# upload file with enctype="multipart/form-data" got strange file name when the filename is Thai

Tags: java, html, servlets, encoding, ajaxform

I am trying to upload file using enctype="multipart/form-data" to servlet. Everything works fine with English file name but when I upload file with Thai file name, the file name get from servlet Part is not Thai.

I have tried enctype="multipart/form-data;charset:utf8" --> still not work
I have tried to encode String file name with utf-8 --> still not work

Anyway to encrypt, please help

Note: I adopt ajaxForm to help submit form

```
$("#uploadform").ajaxForm({
```

Comment: I am not sure what the problem with it. Sorry if I misunderstood it as encryption. It is about the language changed when uploading file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Fixed the tags for you. Anyway, the solution is to use the same encoding in both the client and the server. UTF-8 is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the tags. I already have <meta charset="utf-8" /> for html then I have tired encoding with UTF-8 with the file name got from Servlet Part. Still not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

in the servlet before anything else ?

Comment: It works! Thanks so much :)